# Loading images in WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimage, watchkit

I was loading images as background to a `WKInerfaceGroup` object using `setImageName:`. But now, I need to do some treatments to the images before they are actually displayed. So, I am calling `+imageName:` from `UIImage` with the same exact name, but the image won't load. Why one method works but the other doesn't?

I am using using Xcode 7 beta 4 and Watch OS 2 simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the images in a `xcassettes` file solved the issue.